# Initializing an input tag(html) in a jsp using a bean message tag (i18n)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, javabeans

Am new to JavaEE,so am still trying to find my feet. Well,in order to internationalize my pages,am trying to initialize an input text tag using a bean message tag.

This is what i would have done if i wasn't interested in internationalizing my value attribute :

```
<tr>
 <td><bean:message key="form.birthdate" /><span>:</span></td>
   <td><html:text property="day" value="day" /></td>
     <td><html:text property="month" value="month" /></td>
    <td><html:text property="year" value="year" /></td>
</tr>
```

Now,i decided to initialize using a javascript file :

```
function initialise(){
document.getElementById("day").value="<bean:message key="form.day" />";
document.getElementById("month").value="<bean:message key="form.month" />";
document.getElementById("year").value="<bean:message key="form.year" />";
 }
```

so i call the function initialise() in my jsp :

```
<body onLoad="initialise();">
```

But it doesn't have any effect and i don't know why. I'lld really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`html:text` should generate input box with an attribute `name`. In your javascript you try to access this textbox by Id. In order to make it possible try to add `styleId` attribute to  your `html:text` elements.
So it will look like:

```
<html:text property="day" styleId="day" value="day" />
```

And do the same for month and year.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out i had to use simple quotes in my initialise() function coupled with the styleId attribute already mentioned. So,in my jsp file i'll have :

```
<script type="text/javascript>
  function initialise(){
document.getElementById("day").value='<bean:message key="form.day" />';
document.getElementById("month").value='<bean:message key="form.month" />';
document.getElementById("year").value='<bean:message key="form.year" />';
}
</script>


<tr>
<td><bean:message key="form.birthdate" /><span>:</span></td>
 <td><html:text property="day" value="day" styleId="day" /></td>
 <td><html:text property="month" value="month" styleId="month" /></td>
<td><html:text property="year" value="year" styleId="year" /></td>
</tr>
```